# How to setup UTF-8 in Python SOAPpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, utf-8, soappy

I try to use SOAPpy to connect to a webservice. Each of the Methods from the Service uses Username an Passwort to authentification.
The Passwort has one special german char ("ä").

When i am excecuting the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from SOAPpy import WSDL
server = WSDL.Proxy('http://www.example.com/xxx.asmx?WSDL')
server.HelloWorld("xxx","xxxäxxx")
```

I get this Output in Terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 6, in <module>
    server.HelloWorld("xxx","xxxäxxx")
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 470, in __call__
    return self.__r_call(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 492, in __r_call
    self.__hd, self.__ma)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 354, in __call
    config = self.config, noroot = self.noroot)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/SOAPBuilder.py", line 636, in buildSOAP
    return t.build()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/SOAPBuilder.py", line 147, in build
    self.dump(i, typed = typed, ns_map = ns_map)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/SOAPBuilder.py", line 303, in dump
    meth(obj, tag, typed, ns_map)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/SOAPBuilder.py", line 376, in dump_string
    typed, ns_map, self.genroot(ns_map), id))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/SOAPpy/SOAPBuilder.py", line 339, in dumper
    "id": id, "attrs": a}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can i setup/init SOAPpy to work with UTF-8?

Comment: After this i runed into a second problem. I now use suds to Connect to the Microsoft Webservice:from suds.client import Client
client = Client('http://www.example.com/xxx.asmx?wsdl')
print client.service.HelloWorld("xxx", u"xxxäxxx")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use unicode strings:

```
server.HelloWorld("xxx", u"xxxäxxx")
```